# python run program which requires password from user

Tags: python, pexpect

I am writing an automation script with Python in Linux. It calls another process which requires the user to enter a password.

I have implemented it using [pexpect](https://github.com/pexpect/pexpect) where I just spawn the command and then do an interact.

Is there an alternative method? I cannot use pexpect as I need to run a script on a machine which does not have pexpect installed.

Answer (score 1):

I've seen code that does this with `ssh` by using things like `popen`/`subprocess` and standard streams.

But this is a very bad practice (requires to keep the password in clear text in a relatively easily-accessible place and doesn't allow to change it easily).

- In fact, the code I mentioned caused a problem at my previous occupation: I installed a client key on the server, and the script didn't any longer see the password prompt when it expected to!

So I do recommend to run the program in such a way (options, configuration files, `sudo` etc.) that entering a password manually is not needed.